# How to stop fetching data from json after sending a new request android retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit2

In my app I use `Retrofit` and I have such situation:my app contains bottomNavigationView with 5 items which are assigned to a certain fragment, each fragment at `onCreateView()` method has method call at which we send request to API. I can create a situation when I can send several requests when I tap on different items for replacing current fragment. I would like to prevent sending several requests if it's possible. I have some thoughts about it:

1. Use dispatcher at retrofit client with max requests - `setMaxRequests(1)`
2. Make retrofit client to clear all request - `client.dispatcher().cancelAll()`
3. Check when current fragment is visible to user and make request - `userVisibleHint`

Or someone had similar problem and knows how to solve it. What I see at logs  after tapping several times for example on one item of bottomNavigationView - several requests and several responses. Hope you will help me :)

Comment: instead of calling api in fragment, you can call them in parent activity and pass data to fragment using interface or you can use RxJava.

Answer (score 0):

Your fragments can be recreated everytime you replace fragment. This means you send request each replacement. You can prevent this situation aplying [this solution.](https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711)

Comment: I tried to use `show/hide` but I couldn't see fragment content, so I rejected this solution, but anyway this is the best one :)